# Makefile applies a rule recursively even if it shouldn't

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a very bizzare problem with GNU make. I have the following files:

```
a/x.html
b/Makefile
b/c/Makefile
```

The contents of `a/x.html` are irrelevant. The contents of `b/Makefile` are as follows:

```
SRC=../a
all: x.html

%.html: ${SRC}/%.html
        rsync $< $@
```

The contents of `b/c/Makefile` are the same, except for the definition of `SRC`:

```
SRC=../../a
```

If I run `make` in `b/c/` the result is as expected:

```
rsync ../../a/x.html x.html
```

and `x.html` gets copied from `a/` to `b/c/`.

However, if I run `make` in `b/` the output I get is several lines of:

```
make: stat: ../a/../a/.. (repeated many times) ../a/x.html: File name too long
```

It seems that `make` is applying the rule for `%.html` recursively, but why? Is there something obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build a target that matches the pattern `%.html` (i.e. any target name that ends in `.html`), make applies the rule if it can build the dependency (target built from the original target with `../a/` prepended).

1. You ask to build `x.html`. This matches the pattern `%.html`, so the rule applies: make sees if it can build `../a/x.html`.
2. `../a/x.html` matches the pattern `%.html`, so the rule applies: make sees if it can build `../a/../a/x.html`.
3. `../../a/x.html` matches the pattern `%.html`, so the rule applies, etc.

The stem character can match any part of a path, including directory separators.

You can see what make is trying by running `make -r -d` (`-d` to show debugging output, `-r` to turn off built-in rules which would cause a huge amount of noise).

When you're in `b/c`, this stops at step 2 because `../../a/x.html` exists but `../../../../a/x.html` doesn't.

One way to fix this is to list the files on which you want to act. You can build that list from the list of files that already exist in `../a`:

```
$(notdir $(wildcard ${SRC}/*.html)): %.html: ${SRC}/%.html
        rsync $< $@
```

This has the downside that if the HTML files in `../a` are themselves built by a rule in `b/Makefile`, then running `make` in `b` won't built them in a pristine source directory. This shouldn't be a problem though: it would be unusual to have a makefile in `b` build things outside `b`.

Another approach which doesn't have this defect is to use an absolute path.

```
%.html: $(abspath ${SRC})/%.html
        rsync $< $@
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I'll use the abspath solution.